# storing login state without a session (GWT)?

Tags: session, gwt, authentication

I just thought about writing a GWT app that just works as a client for a RESTful web service. The web service requires HTTP basic authentication for each call.

Since the client is not 'connected' with the server over a session, I have to remember the authentication credentials on the client side. I could do this within the GWT application, but with this, the client has to log in after every reload, which is not very beautiful. I also don't think it's a good idea to write this information to cookies, since everyone could read them.

So, who knows what I am looking for? :-)

Answer (score 0):

Browsers save the username/password information for a given server/port/domain. So if the client has to login once (at least via the browser standard BASIC http dialog) it's preserved over the reloads.

I don't know if you can do that. Maybe forcing the user to navigate to a page inside the domain (or realm) and then using GWT...

Comment: Thanks for this hint. Currently I don't know how I will solve this problem, but in the meantime I found another question (and helpful answer) dealing with log in to RESTful apps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/544474/