# Access Session in WCF service from WebHttpBinding

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I'm using WCF service (via WebGet attribute).

I'm trying to access Session from WCF service, but HttpContext.Current is null

I added AspNetCompatibilityRequirements and edited web.config but I still cannot access session.

Is it possible to use WebGet and Session together?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is possible. If you edit the `web.config`:

```
<system.serviceModel>
   <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

and add the `AspNetCompatiblityRequirements`, the `HttpContext.Current` should be available.

Check everything once again, maybe you've put the attribute in the wrong place (the interface instead of the class?).

Comment: I have attribute, but there is no session. Is WebHttpBinding compatible with session?

Answer (score 4):

A RESTfull service with a session?

See excellent discussion here: [Can you help me understand this? "Common REST Mistakes: Sessions are irrelevant"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/544474/can-you-help-me-understand-this-common-rest-mistakes-sessions-are-irrelevant)

http://javadialog.blogspot.co.uk/2009/06/common-rest-mistakes.html (point 6)

and

http://www.peej.co.uk/articles/no-sessions.html

Quote from Paul Prescod:

> Sessions are irrelevant.
>
> There should be no need for a client to "login" or "start a connection." HTTP authentication is done
>   automatically on every message. Client applications are consumers of
>   resources, not services. Therefore there is nothing to log in to!
>   Let's say that you are booking a flight on a REST web service. You
>   don't create a new "session" connection to the service. Rather you ask
>   the "itinerary creator object" to create you a new itinerary. You can
>   start filling in the blanks but then get some totally different
>   component elsewhere on the web to fill in some other blanks. There is
>   no session so there is no problem of migrating session state between
>   clients. There is also no issue of "session affinity" in the server
>   (though there are still load balancing issues to continue).