# How to create and destroy session in Spring REST Webservice called from Mobile client

Tags: java, spring, web-services, rest, session

I have Spring REST webserivce 
Now from a mobile client webservice is getting called.
First, login method is called for log in succes or failure based on sent value userid and password.

```
      @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST,       headers="Accept=application/json")
     public @ResponseBody List<LogInStatus> getLogIn(@RequestBody LogIn person , HttpServletRequest request) {
              // Call service here
             List<LogInStatus> lList = logInService.getUser(person);
//service method and then in DAO database method is there

             return lList;
     }
```

Now, for many other call, I need logged in user based values, so need to keep session and need to get current user.And at log out call, need to destroy session.
How to do this and achieve,please help with ideas.

Comment: Don't involve HTTPSession in a REST Service anyway: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/544474/can-you-help-me-understand-this-common-rest-mistakes-sessions-are-irrelevant

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't need to create session manually - this is done by servlet container.

You can obtain session from HttpServletRequest

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
```

or just add it as a method parameter, and Spring MVC will inject it for you:

```
public @ResponseBody List<LogInStatus> getLogIn(@RequestBody LogIn person , HttpServletRequest request, HttpSession httpSession)
```

You then can save user details in session via `setAttribute()`/`getAttribute()`.

However, you are much better off using Spring Security, which is intended just for the task - see @Pumpkins's answer for references. `SecurityContext` contains info about currently logged in principal, which you can obtain from `SecurityContextHolder`

Comment: Does this break the `code of being stateless` for RESTful API? See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34130036/how-to-understand-restful-api-is-stateless

Comment: Check here `Common REST mistakes` (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/544474/can-you-help-me-understand-this-common-rest-mistakes-sessions-are-irrelevant)

Answer (score 3):

You need to integrate spring security in your project and make your rest calls via authentication verifier tokens.

You may refer to the documentation :

http://projects.spring.io/spring-security/

Or this nice tutorial can jumpstart your implementation :

http://www.networkedassets.com/configuring-spring-security-for-a-restful-web-services/