# How to get the JSESSIONID from a HTTP request using ContainerRequestContext?

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs

I have the following HTTP headers in a request and I want to extract the `JSESSIONID` from it:

```
Accept=application/json
Accept-Encoding=gzip
deflate,Accept-Language=en-us
Connection=keep-alive
Content-Length=0
Content-Type=application/json
Cookie=JSESSIONID=ss0ox8w99o9142b73rssvc0r
Host=localhost:8080
User-Agent=Test_QA/34 CFNetwork/711.5.7 Darwin/14.5.0 (x86_64)
```

I'm using a `ContainerRequestContext` as following:

```java
@Override
public void filter(final ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("***HEADER VALUE**: " + requestContext.getHeaderString("Cookie"));
}
```

Getting result as:

```
JSESSIONID=zv71od6l2fd41hv6yf0980khy
```

And:

```java
@Override
public void filter(final ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
    Map<String, javax.ws.rs.core.Cookie> clientCookie = requestContext.getCookies();
    System.out.println("Client Cookie Map: " + clientCookie);
}
```

Getting result as:

```
Clinet Cookie Map: {JSESSIONID=JSESSIONID=1of1x5u1s1l4hdxfg2azlep42}
```

What is the best way to extract the `JSESSIONID` from the request?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### A step back

First of all, REST and session identifiers don't sound well in the same sentence.

The *S* in *REST* means *stateless* and not *stateful*. In REST applications, the session state must be managed by the client and not by the server. Consequently, there must not be any session identifiers.

For more information, have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34131829/1426227) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34155259/1426227).

### Getting a value from a cookie in JAX-RS

I think you are looking for the following solution:

```java
Cookie cookie = requestContext.getCookies().get("JSESSIONID");
String value = cookie.getValue();
```

For more information about [`Cookie`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Cookie.html), have a look at the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Cookie.html).