# Why laravel creates token on each request?

Tags: php, laravel, api, authentication, token

I have the following code which utilizes Laravel Passport:

```
if(Auth::attempt($input, true)) {
    return \Auth::user()->createToken(Auth::user()->name, []);
}
```

So, when user logins every time, Laravel creates token over and over again. If this goes on happening, then database will overload for sure. Maybe I haven't yet understood how API Auth works.

Is there a way to prevent Laravel from doing this or is this what is to be expected?

Comment: What you can do is delete the token whenever user `logout()` so this wont create multiple entry for the user.

Comment: @Exterminator That's a cool idea!

Comment: But it has one loop hole you can't keep session on multiple system so if you want to keep it on one system you can do that.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike in a regular web app context, where you have sessions which preserve (logged in) state, a (RESTful) API is generally expected to be stateless. That means that a request would not have to depend on requests that happened previously. Everything necessary for a request, including authentication and authorization, should be handled in each separate request.

For more details see [Cassio Mazzochi Molin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1426227/cassio-mazzochi-molin)'s [explanation of stateless Restful applications](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34131829/5165149).

Kind regards,

Draco

Comment: Thanks for the resource. I am using Authorization Bearer to handle auth!

Answer (score 0):

The traditional process of interacting with a website is that you login from the login page. Next, you perform you desired actions and then log out. However, in the case of REST API, the process is quite different. The traditional procedure does not work in the case of RESTful APIs because the methods used on login page does not make any sense. You need to use api_token instead.

All you need to do is to append the api_token to the query string before making a request and the  request is authenticated.

Now what Laravel 5.5 offers is quite interesting! You can easily implement this idea using the [Passport library](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/api-token-authentication-laravel-5-5/).