# Is it wrong to use Redis(to store user related data) in a Stateless(REST) API?

Tags: node.js, rest, redis, api-design

I was building a nodejs chat app using socket.io. And i need to store a map with **user->socketID** key->value pairs(*my messages will have a sender and receiver and so i can send to the intended receiver if i have the socket they are in*).
I could use a global variable to do it. But then that makes it stateful. So i was wondering since Redis is an in-memory cache(*It stores data in ram i think??*) service. Does storing data in it also makes my api stateful.Because we are still storing some info about users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Storting any kind of user information on the server violates the rules of **Stateless REST API**,
In stateless REST API, Client is responsible to send you all data that you require to process on server.
Please go through these links to have a better understading.

[How to understand "RESTful API is stateless"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34130036/how-to-understand-restful-api-is-stateless)

https://restfulapi.net/statelessness/