# Laravel Auth middleware Auth::user() returns null when Auth::attempt and Auth::login returned true

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

Project setup

Front-end

- hosted by using node server via npm start (example will be called localhost:3000)

Back-end

- hosted in my apache (example will be called localhost:4000)

So the current problem is that when I login via `port 3000` it returns the user details including my CSRF token. `Auth::attempt` and `Auth::login` works just fine.

But when I go to an endpoint that has an Auth middleware it returns `Unauthorized`, when I remove the middleware and query for the current user `Auth::user()` it returns `null`.

Hints the laravel_session tokens are different when logging in and when calling another endpoint

```
Login API 

Set-Cookie: 
laravel_session=m7aRXgtBELRJInj4Dc12FJIaIkZFhgVZrUDBuQVE; expires=Fri, 28-Apr-2023 09:08:39 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; domain=http://localhost; secure; httponly; samesite=lax


/user/current API
Set-Cookie: Set-Cookie: 
laravel_session=eQfSPF1d1KRypoktEMtLpvgdZ5zQKJRAXaexlIml; expires=Fri, 28-Apr-2023 09:20:04 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; domain=http://localhost; secure; httponly; samesite=lax
```

**Kernel.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http;

use App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate;
use App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies;
use App\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance;
use App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated;
use App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings;
use App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies;
use App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken;
use Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors;
use Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth;
use Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize;
use Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified;
use Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\RequirePassword;
use Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize;
use Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders;
use Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings;
use Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests;
use Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature;
use Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession;
use Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession;
use Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        // \App\Http\Middleware\TrustHosts::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        TrustProxies::class,
        HandleCors::class,
        PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance::class,
        ValidatePostSize::class,
        TrimStrings::class,
        ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware groups.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
            EncryptCookies::class,
            AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            StartSession::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            SubstituteBindings::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
            // 'throttle:api',
            HandleCors::class,
            SubstituteBindings::class,
            AuthenticateSession::class,
            StartSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class,
        ],
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware.
     *
     * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'sessions' => StartSession::class,
        'auth' => Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'cache.headers' => SetCacheHeaders::class,
        'can' => Authorize::class,
        'guest' => RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'password.confirm' => RequirePassword::class,
        'signed' => ValidateSignature::class,
        'throttle' => ThrottleRequests::class,
        'verified' => EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
        'cors' => \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class,
    ];
}
```

**auth.php**

```
<?php

return [

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'passport',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
    ],


    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\User::class,
        ],

        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],

 

    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],
    ],

    'password_timeout' => 10800,

];
```

**AuthServiceProvider.php**

```
class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The policy mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $policies = [
        'App\Models\Model' => 'App\Policies\ModelPolicy',
    ];

    /**
     * Register any authentication / authorization services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();

        if (!$this->app->routesAreCached()) {
            Passport::routes();
        }

        // Passport::loadKeysFrom(__DIR__.'/../secrets/oauth');
    }
}
```

**login method**

```
public function loginUser(Request $request, LoginResponse $loginResponse)
{
    if (Auth::attempt(['username' => $request->username, 'password' => $request->password], true)) {
        $user = Auth::user();


        Auth::login($user);
        $user_login_token = Auth::user()->createToken('API Token')->accessToken;


        $ret = [
            'status' => true,
            'message' => 'User authenticated',
            'data' => $user_login_token,
            'first_time_login' => $user->first_time_login,
            'user' => $user,
            'csrf_token' => csrf_token(),
            'user_login_token' => DB::table('personal_access_tokens')->where('id', $user_login_token->id)->first()->token
        ];

        return response($ret, 200);
    }
}
```

**REST**

```
var res = await fetch('http://localhost:480/app/api/test/laravel', {
  method: 'GET', headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json", "Accept": "application/json", "Authorization": `Bearer {csrf_token_here}` },
});

if (res.ok) {
  var data = await res.json();
  console.log(data);
} else {
  console.error('Failed to fetch data:', res.status, res.statusText);
}
```

laravel_session= on set_cookies when calling the endpoints are different from logging in and during fetch. There must be something wrong with the setup for session. I suspect

Comment: The `Authorization` header shouldn't be a `csrf_token`, it should be `user_login_token`, csrf is not auth by `Authorization` header.

Comment: We also tried using the user_login_token just to try every token. It still returns the same error.

Comment: API is stateless. If the `Auth::user()` return null, it means your `Authorization` token is not correct, it has not matched to any user token.

Comment: I've not used passport before, so can't give you some example code. :(

Comment: I updated some of the things we noticed. The laravel session token is different everytime we call `res`

Comment: As I said, API is stateless, API request is not getting auth user by a session, it get the user info by a bearer token.

Comment: You may get some useful information from this answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34131829

Answer (score 0):

Driver should not be using session if you want to use Auth tokens. I used JWT auth instead. Thank you